# Exporting data from SQL server to PostgreSQL limited 100 records

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, limit, dbmigrate

I have a database in SQL Server, but now I must transfer to PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to the way:

1. Right-click on the database
2. Task/ExportData
3. Choose the database input [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtq44.jpg)
4. Choose the database output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgBF4.jpg)
5. Choose 'Copy data from one or more tables or views'
6. Notification success with a total of 4477 rows transferred [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7yNb.jpg)

But, when I check the database in PostgreSQL, I just have 100-row and I re-tried another table but it's always 100-row.
Somehow it's limited results.
Is there a more efficient way for large numbers of results?

Comment: Did you COUNT(*) the number of records?

Comment: Yes, I did, @FrankHeikens

Comment: How exactly are you checking the data in PostgreSQL? For example... if you use pgAdmin, right-click on the table, choose View/Edit Data and then choose "First 100 rows" or "Last 100 rows" then it's obviously only going to show you 100 rows.

Comment: Just a guess, are you using some trial postgres driver? They sometimes put some limitations in

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I know "first 100" and "last 100" but besides that, there is also an "all rows" option, I have checked on PgAdmin vs Dbeaver, or using the query select count(*) command. but it's alway return 100